# Updating a PostgreSQL table based on a foreign key match with another table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, foreign-keys, subquery

Suppose I have a value for column in table First_Table: column_a = 123. It has column_a, column_b, and column_e. First_Table shares a one-to-many foreign key column with Second_Table: column_b. Second_Table has column_b, column_c, and column_e. Here's a sample dataset for the 2 tables.

```
             First_Table                          Second_Table    
column_a | column_b  | column_e           column_b | column_c | column_e 
---------|-----------|---------           ---------|----------|---------
123      |  a        | Joe                 a       |  False   |  horse
234      |  b        | Sally               f       |  True    |  dog      
123      |  d        | Andre               c       |  False   |  cat
```

I want to update column_c in Second_Table to be True based on the column_b matches between the 2 tables where column_a = 123 in First_Table. I can select all the matching records using this:

```
WITH Temp AS (
    SELECT column_b
    FROM First_Table 
    WHERE column_b = 123
)
SELECT this.*
FROM Second_Table this,
     Temp that
WHERE this.column_b = that.column_b
```

Now I want to update Second_Table to set column_c = True based on these matching records? I essentially want Second Table to return this after the update:

```
    Second_Table
column_b | column_c | column_e
---------|----------|---------
 a       |  True    |  horse
```

Comment: Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts),and  the expected results of that data, all as text - **no images**.  Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.

Comment: What hinders you from using an `UPDATE` of "*Second_Table.column_c*" value in place of the `SELECT` that is currently working correctly for you?

Comment: This is not one to many! First_Table column b values is {a,b,d}. Second_Table column b values is {a,f,c}.

Comment: Check your query: you're using `this` alias even though it's never referenced before, and you're filtering on `column_b = 123` where "*column_b*" never assumes that value. If there's a one-to-many correspondence between the two tables, make the sample data reflect this behaviour too and update the expected output accordingly (if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update second_table t2
set 
    column_c = true 
from 
    first_table t1 
where 
    t1.column_b = t2.column_b 
    and t1.column_a = 123
returning 
    t1.column_b, t2.column_c, t2.column_e; 

Result: 
column_b    column_c    column_e
a           true        horse
```

Comment: Yep, that works. I think my mistake was having the second_table added in the from clause.